# Automatically insert Line break?

Tags: php, database

I'm making a news posting system and I was wondering if it is possible to automatically insert a `<br />` tag where ever there is a new line?

For example, if posted a news article with the following text in the text area:

```
New news article

Features
- 1
- 2
- 3
```

it would add this to the news database:

```
New news article<br/>
<br/>
Features<br/>
- 1<br/>
- 2<br/>
- 3<br/>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Apply the <br> tag when you **OUTPUT** data not when you store it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
nl2br($article)
```

http://www.php.net/nl2br

Answer (score 0):

nl2br($string_name, false);
// where string name is the name of your variable.

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of a previous answer, but including an optional parameter changing the default value. In fact, using `false` would make the resulting replacement different of what was stated in the example by the question's author.

Answer (score -2):

You should replace "\n" character with "br" tag while parsing $_POST data.

For example:

```
/**
 * Cleans incoming data
 *
 * @param array $data - Incoming data, $_GET or $_POST, for example
 * @return void
 */     
function cleanPost(&$data)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
    {
        if (!is_array($v))
        {
            // Your filters here
            $v = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $v);
        }
        $data[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should *not* generally apply HTML-specific methods to all incoming data. Only if and *when* you're outputting to HTML is this really necessary.

Comment: You should add the <br>s to data pulled from the database instead of saving it as formatted.